# Remove Previous Word in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, settings, keyboard-shortcuts

I am having an issue with the `Remove Previous Word` shortcut in MATLAB.

It works in the editor, but not in the command window. I tried to edit it in the keyboard shortcut preferences page, but you are only allowed to select `MATLAB Editor` in the `Tools with shortcut` section, it does not give you the option to add the `Command Window`.

Does anyone have a workaround for this, or at least know a reason why this wouldn't be implemented for the command window?

Comment: The command window uses the xterm keyboard shortcuts, so try ctrl-w.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 That tries to close the current window, it doesn't seem to do anything on command window.

Comment: It might just be on linux that matlab tries to act like an xterm. I thought it worked on all platforms, but I guess not. You can try them all out and see which ones work. A list of the standard xterm shortcuts is [here](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_use_short-cut_keys_in_xterm_and_other_terminals).

Comment: It looks like Alt-Backspace would do it too, but in MATLAB, that's undo. Ctrl+k might be pretty useful if I can remember to use it. Thanks for the info!